# Wifi Router number of ports

Tags: networking

For some reason, the majority of consumer wifi routers are limited to 4 ports. Is there a technical reason for limiting the number of ports on wifi routers to 4 ports?

Comment: Yes, the physical circuits inside support multiples of 4. If they add more than 4, the next step would be 8, and that would increase the costs. That is why almost every switch you purchase has multiples of 4 ports. There are other ICs that handle 5-ports, 6-ports, 7-ports, but apparently this is non-standard enough to be unreasonable to use in the mainstream.

Comment: No technical reason. It is limited to 4 ports for home use simply because of form factor and functionality. Most people are not going to need more than 4 and it fits almost anywhere. There is also something to be said for the processing power onboard. If there were more ports, more data, more packet analysis would require a better processor (maybe) thus also becoming more expensive.

Comment: Don't expect a 3-in-one combo device to cover every use case ever... Since adding more ports is as easy as grabbing a switch, why _would_ they make a combo "wifi router" with a massive amount of ports anyway?

Comment: “Is there a technical reason for limiting the number of ports on wifi routers to 4 ports?” - Lack of consumer demand.  Any other explanation is pure speculation including this explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is simply that most devices connect wirelessly today. Consumer applications that would have more than four wired devices in the same physical location as the router are rare.

A typical home user might have a desktop near the router. And they might have a printer that uses a wired connection. But typically, that's it.

Typical cheap low-end switching ICs have five ports. The router needs one port for its CPU to connect to the devices on the LAN. That leaves four.

A switch to expand the number of LAN ports is absurdly cheap. A 5-port Gigabit switch, which would add three more ports, is about $15. An 8-port Gigabit switch, which would add six more ports, is about $25.

Comment: I needed to add an 8-port Gigabit switch: I guess I am atypical :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this has a lot to do with geometry and economics. Usually each port will be multiplexed on to several ports while some will be dedicated. On business network switches there is usually one or two dedicated ports or these are used as expansion ports. On a home router the layout is usually a SOC with one Ethernet port and a switch module on the PCI bus totally 5 ports.

The ports will be in factors of 2 due to multiplexing. So that leaves 2 or 4 as options. While many components such as the physical connectors come in packs of 4 or 6. The isolation transformers used for all category cables usually come in 4 or 8.

So thats why you won't easily find a switch with 10 ports unless the last 2 are dedicated ports or expanders. Having a switch with a factor of 2 ports would mean having double the number of switch logic chips. and economically its not worth bothering have a hybrid of some 4 port and some 2 port in the same device.

Answer (score 1):

**Beware the difference between a Router and a Switch**

While not a full excuse in and of itself, it is worth noting that a router and a switch are functionally expected to be two different things (currently blurred by the existance of [Layer 3 Switches](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/tip/Layer-3-switches-explained)).  The basic point here is that a router is actually expected to have fewer ports as it's job is to 'route' a connection between two areas.

In function this means bringing in your WAN connection and translating it (using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)) to your local network.  In the old days Routers were naturally expected to have only two ports, one for the WAN and one for the LAN.  Consumer routers changed this to 4 due mostly to the much more common 4 port interface chips than the 1 port ones.

Switches, commonly, come with large batches of ports as their job is just to split up the traffic according to [ARP](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Address-Resolution-Protocol-ARP) tables.  They don't have to worry about messy things like NAT, firewalls, port forwarding and the host of other messy things routers commonly do.

Comment: "*Consumer routers changed this to 4 due mostly to the much more common 4 port interface chips than the 1 port ones.*" Huh? The chips have 5 ports and one of the ports connects to the router's CPU. To have just one port, you wouldn't need a switch chip at all.